# Free API To Get Ethereum Price

Tags: external-api

I am looking for a free api to get `ETHEREUM CRYPTO CURRENCY PRICE`.
Entire yesterday i was searching google & test many web sites.
But result was zero for ethereum price.
Here is what i tried :
1.
https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=USD,EUR
It seems this api has 100,000 calls limitation in one month or has other limitations.
2.
https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd
It has id error many times
3.
https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/guides/price-data
Only has bitcoin price

I am so confused for fetch `ETHEREUM PRICE`.
What is your suggestion?

Comment: Please consider my question again. That answer in that thread could not help me.    
https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/pricing   
Please see this link > It says free api has 250,000 calls limitation for lifetime & 100,000 calls limitation for one month.

Comment: I searched many places to get ethereum price with no help.